# Swift 3 - save json using struct model with null value

Tags: ios, json, struct, swift3

I am working on consuming the restful web service which returns the data in JSON format. This is the Sample data :

```
[
{
    "name": "Mark E",
    "categories": "process",
    "id": 1,
    "checkedOut": null,
    "checkedOutBy": null
},
{
    "name": "John",
    "categories": null,
    "id": 2,
    "checkedOut": null,
    "checkedOutBy": null
}
]
```

I am parsing this json using this code. Also I created struct model for this.

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        var myModel = [MyModel]()
        if let HTTPResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            let status = HTTPResponse.statusCode
            if(status == 200) {

                guard let data = data else {
                    print("No Data!!")
                    return completion(false, myModel)
                }
                guard let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSArray else {
                    print("Not an array")
                    return completion(false, myModel)
                }

                for jsondata in json {
                    guard let newdata = MyModel(json: jsondata) else {
                        continue
                    }
                    myModel.append(newdata)
                }
                completion(true,myModel)
            }else {
                completion(false,myModel)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

And this is my data model struct

```
struct MyModel {
var name : String
var categories : String
var id : Int
var checkedOut : String
var checkedOutBy : String

init?(json:Any) {
    guard let myModel = json as? NSDictionary else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let name = myModel["name"] as? String,
          let id = myModel["id"] as? Int else {
            return nil
    }

    self.name = author
    self.id = id

   // This is how I am handling the null values. 
   if let categories = myModel["categories"] as? String {
        self.categories = categories
    } else {
        self.categories = ""
    }

    if let lastCheckedOut = myModel["lastCheckedOut"] as? String {
        self.lastCheckedOut = lastCheckedOut
    } else {
        self.lastCheckedOut = ""
    }

    if let lastCheckedOutBy = myModel["lastCheckedOutBy"] as? String {
        self.lastCheckedOutBy = lastCheckedOutBy
    }else {
        self.lastCheckedOutBy = ""
    }
  }
}
```

Here in `struct MyModel`, I am using `if let` for checking null values. Could anyone please suggest me this is the right way to check each variable for null? Is there any other way to do this?

If I check for null value using `guard`, its not adding any object into array.

If the value is null then it simply assign empty char `""` to that variable and it will add into MyModel array of objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to check for a specific type and assign something else on failure is the *nil coalescing operator*:

```
self.lastCheckedOut = myModel["lastCheckedOut"] as? String ?? ""
```

Side-note: Consider that JSON `null` is deserialized to `NSNull` rather than to `nil`

Comment: I am new to iOS programming.Could you please guide/comment on my code. 
Is this the right way to parse the json and save into struct model? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically it's a feasible and reliable way. However you should use native Swift collection types rather than Foundation `NSArray / NSDictionary`. And if the returned data always contains at least the name you don't need a failable initializer. And if the properties / members of the struct are supposed to be constants you can even declare them as `let`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will update my code. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise on a couple of approaches:

1. Setting MyModel struct properties as optionals. In this way, you don't need to use `if let` or `guard` statements.

   2. I can recommend ObjectMapper, a Swift 3 pods which maps JSON very efficiently. For example:

Instead of assigning:

`If let _value = dictionary["value"] as? String { self.value = _value
 }`

You will use

```
self.value = map["value"]
```

[ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper)
 Wrote this on my phone, untested ;-)...

Comment: `ObjectMapper` is overkill for that particular purpose.

Comment: It's not, been using it for a very longs time. Perfect for json with optinal values, also makes your code much more readable.. ;-)

Comment: I wrote *for that particular purpose*. For one class with 5 properties it's less code – and less effort to install CocoaPods – without the library

Comment: Well, I would assume he would need this across his entire project, which might be a good setup. But this is a matter of preference. I also advised ObjectMapper as a general library to work with JSON.

Comment: Thanks Tal Zion for your suggestion. I will check the ObjectMapper library. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome ;-), looking at your code, although there are many ways to parse JSON, this is not the ideal way ;-). You can trim it down to 5 lines of code by setting all properties to optionals.

Comment: Yeah sure. I will read more on this. 
I am referring this link https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37